# How to store the update of my javascript function in cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have made a function for adding rows in a table and storing info in the cells. But when i refresh the page all the update is gone. I know that this can be solved with php but i can't use php because this is a project for school and i can use only javascript and cookies. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this :

```
document.cookie = "cookie_name=cookie_value";
```

Example:

```
document.cookie = "cell_1_1=hello";
```